# scala list java.lang.String

Tags: string, list, scala

So this is my code:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.MutableList 

val list = MutableList[Any]()
val input = scala.io.StdIn.readLine("Please enter your list of values separated by a comma:").split(",")
val toList = for (e <- input if(!e.trim.isEmpty())) yield e.trim.toString
list += toList
println(list)
```

But when the "list" gets printed it doesn't show me the input seperated by commas, besides it prints the following:

> MutableList([Ljava.lang.String;@d716361)

Why is that so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now your `input` is an `Array` which doesn't have pretty `toString` representation. 
Change your `input` to:

```
val input = scala.io.StdIn.readLine("Please enter your list of values separated by a comma:").split(",").toList
```

Comment: Ah okay. So if I use the .split(",") operator it is putting my input into an array of Strings splitted by a comma? and therefore its not only one string but an array containing strings?

Comment: @ArmaGeddon, exactly!

Comment: ah okay thats explains a lot...But i thought that too because it was always telling me that it has found an Array(String) :)